# using returned value of templatetags by aliasing in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any way to use the return element of templatetags by aliasing ?

For example,

**templatetags.py**

```
@register.simple_tag()
def getCaptionLabel(form,pid):
    return form.__getitem__('caption_%s'%pid)
```

**mypage.html**

```
{% with field = getCaption form photo.pk %}

{{ field.label_tag }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to actually do it in your tag. The Django trunk now has an `assignment_tag` (See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) to allow you to do this easily, but until it hits a release, you'll have to do it the old fashioned way. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context

Comment: More than enough and helpful answer. Thank you !